# Seeing if node has been changed in custom submit handler

Tags: 7, forms

I have written a custom submit handler that gets called whenever a certain content type is edited.

I was wondering if there was a flag in `$form_state` that indicates whether the node was actually edited vs whether someone is just clicking the `save` button without actually changing anything.  I am wondering because I would like to perform an action only if the node is edited. Thank you

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = '_unpublish_new_product';
}

function _unpublish_new_product($form, &$form_state) {
   // is there a flag in $form_state that indicates if any fields were changed so I
   // could perform a conditional action??
}
```

Comment: do you can do your action inside `hook_node_presave($node)`? where you have `$node` and `$node->original` to compare

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't such flag, but you can use [entity_load_unchanged()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load_unchanged/7) to get a copy of the entity before any change, and compare the field value with the one you get from the form.

The function is called, for example, from [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7), which contain the following code.

```
// Load the stored entity, if any.
if (!empty($node->nid) && !isset($node->original)) {
  $node->original = entity_load_unchanged('node', $node->nid);
}

field_attach_presave('node', $node);
global $user;

// Determine if we will be inserting a new node.
if (!isset($node->is_new)) {
  $node->is_new = empty($node->nid);
}

// Set the timestamp fields.
if (empty($node->created)) {
  $node->created = REQUEST_TIME;
}
// The changed timestamp is always updated for bookkeeping purposes,
// for example: revisions, searching, etc.
$node->changed = REQUEST_TIME;

$node->timestamp = REQUEST_TIME;
$update_node = TRUE;

// Let modules modify the node before it is saved to the database.
module_invoke_all('node_presave', $node);
module_invoke_all('entity_presave', $node, 'node');
```

This means that the implementations of [hook_field_attach_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_presave/7), [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7), and [hook_entity_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7) will get the unchanged version of the node object in `$node->original` (or `$entity->original`); if you are writing code for one of these hooks, you don't need to call `entity_load_unchanged()` because `node_save()` already did it for you.

Similar code is present in [comment_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_save/7), [taxonomy_term_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7), [taxonomy_vocabulary_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_vocabulary_save/7), and [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7).

```
if (!empty($comment->cid) && !isset($comment->original)) {
  $comment->original = entity_load_unchanged('comment', $comment->cid);
}

field_attach_presave('comment', $comment);

// Allow modules to alter the comment before saving.
module_invoke_all('comment_presave', $comment);
module_invoke_all('entity_presave', $comment, 'comment');
```

```
  if (!empty($term->tid) && !isset($term->original)) {
    $term->original = entity_load_unchanged('taxonomy_term', $term->tid);
  }

  field_attach_presave('taxonomy_term', $term);
  module_invoke_all('taxonomy_term_presave', $term);
  module_invoke_all('entity_presave', $term, 'taxonomy_term');
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there isn't such a flag. You will have to compare the values yourself I think. For node forms I made this first attempt to compare the node data. This is just a quick idea how a solution could be, maybe I am missing some edge cases where this isn't working, but in my tests with a simple default "page" node form it was working well. (I used the "Preview" button for reloading the form and testing.)

As Mohammad Ali Akbari says, `hook_presave()` might be a better place to compare the data, but the comparison of the flatted arrays should work there, too.

Attribution for the flatten function goes to [Rob Peck](http://www.robpeck.com/2010/06/diffing-flattening-and-expanding-multidimensional-arrays-in-php/).

```
/**
 * @file mymodule.module
 * Do stuff.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Proof of concept of checking for changes to a node in form submit.
 * Uses the default "page" content type.
 *
 * You need devel module to see an nice Krumo of the fields that have changed.
 */
function mymodule_form_page_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //Get uncached data of the current node from the db.
  //Cast the node object to an array so we can use the flatten function
  //and php array_diff functions.
  $node_array_db = (array) node_load($form['#node']->nid,NULL, TRUE);

  //Throw away the changed value as this is alwasy different.
  unset($node_array_db['changed']);

  //Cast the node object to an array so we can use the flatten function
  //and php aray_diff functions.
  $node_array_form = (array) $form_state['node'];

  //The $node object from the form holds some metadata. Throw away the fields
  //in the forms $node object/array that are not in the version from the db.
  $node_array_form = array_intersect_key($node_array_form,$node_array_db );

  //Flatten the nested array structure so we can use array_diff for comparing no
  //matter what the fields are structured.
  $result = array_diff(flatten($node_array_form), flatten($node_array_db));

  //Print all fields with differences in the field values.
  dpm($result);

  if (empty($result)) {
    dpm('No Changes');
    //No changes. Just "Save" was pressed.
  }
  else {
    dpm('There are different field values in this form than those in the database.');
    //Do something.
  }

}

/**
 * Function for flattening an array.
 *
 */
function flatten($arr, $base = "", $divider_char = "/") {
  $ret = array();

  if (is_array($arr)) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
      if (is_array($v)) {
        $tmp_array = flatten($v, $base.$k.$divider_char, $divider_char);
        $ret = array_merge($ret, $tmp_array);
      }
      else {
        $ret[$base.$k] = $v;
      }
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```